# Son, eres or es: which one to use with "the boys"?

Tags: verbos, conjugación

We use 'eres' for 'are' with you in Spanish. We use 'es' with usted for 'are'. If we have to use 'are' with boys, what would we use: *son*, *eres* or *es*?

What would be the appropriate tense for "The boys."?

Answer (score 4):

- Yo soy
- Tu eres
- Él es
- Nosotros somos
- Ustedes son
- Ellos son

which of these pronouns do you think fit "the boys" best? 
As to the translation- any dictionary can help you with that.

Comment: The boys --- Ellos -> therefore you would use "son".

Answer (score 4):

When you use the *usted* form you use the conjugation of the third person, not the second, even if *usted* is used as a polite version of *tú* (thus, second person singular) and *ustedes*  as a polite version of *vosotros* (thus, second person plural).

> Tú eres / Vosotros sois [Second person]
>
> El (o ella) es / Ellos Son [Third person]
>
> Usted es / ustedes son [second person that used third person conjugation]

**We do this when directly addressing someone, as a way of being polite, not when we describe certain collectives.** It doesn't matter if is *boys* or *cars*. What matters is if you want to be super-polite when addressing someone you are talking to.

It is unlikely that you would address a group of boys *de usted* but not impossible. For example if you were their teacher and wanted to be extremely formal you could address the as *usted*.

So with boys or kids or teenagers most likely you will use the *tú* form, so use the second person of whichever verb you are using. If you are not addressing them directly you have no need for the *usted* form.

Nevertheless, being *boys* a plural you are going to use third person.

> Ese chico **está** solo. Esos chicos **están** jugando.

Answer (score 1):

**Son** (They) the boys are mean. = (Ellos) los niños son malos.

It might be **Somos**. We, the boys, are better = Nosotros, los niños, somos mejores.

I *AM*   =  SOY

You, we, you, they - *ARE* = ERES, SOMOS, SON, SON

He, she, it -  *IS*  = ES